# how to deploy project created using Laravel ,React with Inertia

Tags: reactjs, laravel, breeze, inertiajs

I have created a project using Laravel and React with Inertia.
How can I deploy theproject in a shared hosting. When  searched for a solution  found  that need to run "npm run build" to generate the react build.

Do I need to upload entire files including the react files to the live site or  need to upload only the generated build files.

generated build using "npm run build". how can i point the domain to the project

Comment: Only the compiled files are required for react, but laravel will require the php files

Comment: typically though you will just upload the whole project, and run `npm run build` so you only serve the optimised react files to a user

Comment: do i need to move the build folder files to project root folder

Comment: definitely not, you would never want to serve your application files to the internet - The public folder contains the files that you want to serve externally (where the build files are generated)